# Change Status of Drafted page to Published in Programmatically in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Im trying to programmatically change the status of a page that already exists with a status of 'draft' to 'publish' using a custom function.

I have tried using custom SQL queries and $wpdb to explicitly UPDATE the post status using its ID but this causes errors when retrieving the post again in the future. I have no problem changing a published page to draft, but the reverse doesn't seem to work.

```
$post = array( 'ID' => $company_page_id, 'post_status' => 'draft' );
wp_update_post($post);
```

Code above works perfect. My thought was the code below would do the trick, however nothing changes when executed. Are there steps I am missing when changing an existing drafted page to published? Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
$post = array( 'ID' => $company_page_id, 'post_status' => 'publish' );
wp_update_post($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Daemon  can you please check below code?

```
$get_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
$get_post['post_status'] = $status;
wp_update_post($get_post);
```

If it does not work then can you please try this function

```
wp_publish_post()
```